# Error when trying to override aesthetics with geom_rect()

Tags: r, graphics, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to not define the aesthetics in the ggplot function but rather in the following geoms because I plan to use a few.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(10, 20, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(10, 20, replace = TRUE)
)
```

This works :

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x, xmax = x + 1, ymin = y, ymax = y + 2)) +
geom_rect()
```

This doesn't and I obtain "Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot"

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = x, xmax = x + 1, ymin = y, ymax = y + 2))
```

But if I change the geom for geom_point, it works again:

```
ggplot(df) +
geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Seems to work for some people!
When I launch a fresh R session and only load ggplot2, it works for me too.
I'll continue to search for the package responsible for this behaviour

Comment: Both work fine for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error either.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem !

The "ggbio" package (ggbio_1.16.1) is responsible for this behaviour and affects ggplot2 functions.

Not loading "ggbio" solves the problem for me.

Comment: I needed to use ggbio for my plot so I did not want to disable it. Explicitly stating `ggplot2::geom_rect()` in the plot fixed the issue.